# Why do some people put curly braces on the same line as the statement and other people put it on a new line?

Tags: c#, java, javascript, c++, c

Is there any reason why some people choose one over the other or is it just preference?

Also, which do you use and why?

Comment: Because some people are *dumb*. ;)

Comment: Why do some people prefer Coke to Pepsi?

Comment: Yes preference. Some ppl like horizontal spacing and some likes vertical spacing. I am not sure if this question can be answered objectively.

Comment: @Stephen: Because some people are *dumb*. :)

Comment: See.. no. Coke is better from a bottle than Pepsi is, but Pepsi from a can owns Coke every day.

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) is a more detailed explanation on this

Answer (score 1):

100% programmer choice.  It doesn't affect the program itself in any way.

Comment: (unless you're using JavaScript and try to return an object literal ;))

Comment: Worth noting that depending on the language, format is quite important - Python for example.